# Is there a way to find the NBT of a player head?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Let's say I have the head of a player by the name of "Player" (creative, I know). If you have the physical head in your inventory/stored somewhere/in your possession, and that head has the correct NBT (in this case, specifically meaning it has the SkullOwner set to the aforementioned "Player"), is there *any way to find out the NBT in general* of this head?

As far as I know, I don't see there being a way in just vanilla Minecraft without using some sort of item editor or if the item along with its NBT is stored in player.dat, but if there is no possible way to find 100% of an item's NBT, being able to just find the SkullOwner of a certain player head would be good to know too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw the head on the ground and use `/data get entity @e[type=minecraft:item,sort=nearest,limit=1]` to obtain most data contained in the item, including NBT.[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also select the item in your hotbar and use `/data get entity @s SelectedItem`, which reveals only the NBT of the item with less extra data.